# I want to use aioredis connection pool ,not create new connection in every AsyncWebsocketConsumer.connect .Where can I put the code

Tags: python, django-channels

I want to use aioredis connection pool ,not create new connection in every AsyncWebsocketConsumer.connect .Where can I put the code.

Now I create new connection in connect event every time, code like this

```py
async def connect(self):
    self.redis = await aioredis.create_redis(
            'redis://localhost',encoding='utf-8')
async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    await self.redis.close()
```

I need something like  self.channel_layer ,using pool connection across every consumer.
Thanks.

Comment: You can probably put it in the `__init__.py` module of the app as it doesn't called often but on application start.

Comment: @Ken4scholars Could you show me some demo code ?

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the best solution, but you can do this

You app's `__init__.py`

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

redis = async_to_sync(aioredis.create_redis)('redis://localhost',encoding='utf-8')
```

Then in your consumer, you can import and use the existing redis connection

```
from . import redis
```