# Using a single redis connection (aioredis)

Tags: python, redis

My application will be sending hundreds, if not thousands, of messages over redis every second, so we are going to open the connection when the app launches and use that connection for every transaction. I am having trouble keeping that connection open.

Here is some of my redis handler class:

```py
class RedisSingleDatabase(AsyncGetSetDatabase):

    async def redis(self):
        if not self._redis:
            self._redis = await aioredis.create_redis(('redis', REDIS_PORT))
        return self._redis

    def __init__(self):
        self._redis = None

    async def get(self, key):
        r = await self.redis()
        # r = await aioredis.create_redis(('redis', REDIS_PORT))
        print(f'CONNECTION IS {"CLOSED" if r.closed else "OPEN"}!')
        data = await r.get(key, encoding='utf-8')
        if data is not None:
            return json.loads(data)
```

This does not work. By the time we call `r.get`, the connection is closed (`ConnectionClosedError`).

If I uncomment the second line of the `get` method, and connect to the database locally in the method, it works. But then we're no longer using the same connection.

I've considered trying all this using dependency injection as well. This is a flask app, and in my `create_app` method I would connect to the database and construct my `RedisSingleDatabase` with that connection. Besides the question of whether my current problem would be the same, I can't seem to get this approach to work since we need to `await` the connection which I can't do in my root-level `create_app` which can't be async! (unless I'm missing something).

I've tried `asyncio.run` all over the place and it either doesn't fix the problem or raises its own error that it can't be called from a running event loop.

Please help!!!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? It seems like a common issue (trying to use one connection pool in multiple parts of the code) but no clean answers.  I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56218638/656302